# How to combine elements of a list in different ways

Tags: prolog

I want to travel this type of list: `[worker1(J, 10), worker2(T, 20), worker3(P, 30)].`
, first starting by the head, combining it with the next element, and going till the end, and if at that point I do not reach a solution (my problem is affected by the order in which workers come), then I want start with another workers, and explore all other options.

I am not sure whether there is a simple way of doing this, but right now is the only idea I have to try and solve an exercise, so I wanted to ask here. The problem with what I know so far is that I would travel it like this:

w1-w2, w1-w3, w1-w4

if that fails, by recursion, I would skip the head and would have:

w2-w3, w2-w4

but not w2-w1, so I would be missing possible solutions. I found nothing when looking arround so my assumption is that I am not using proper terminology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you Google "prolog combinations of a list", you'll find [Prolog Guide - Combinatorics](http://kti.ms.mff.cuni.cz/~bartak/prolog/combinatorics.html). Here's a slight variation of a predicate shown there that will generate sublists of `N` elements of a given list `L`:

```
comb(0, _, []).
comb(N, [X|T], [X|Comb]) :-
    N #> 0,
    N1 #= N - 1,
    comb(N1, T, Comb).
comb(N, [_|T], [X|Comb]) :-
    N #> 0,
    comb(N, T, [X|Comb]).
```

To get all of the pairs you are after, you can call this with:

```
comb(2, List, Comb).
```

For example:

```
| ?- comb(2, [a,b,c,d], R).

R = [a,b] ? a

R = [a,c]

R = [a,d]

R = [b,c]

R = [b,d]

R = [c,d]

no
```

If you want dash pairs, you could just map them with:

```
pair_list_dash([X,Y], X-Y).
```